# Why do I have to press C-b twice to move one char back in bash emacs mode?

Tags: bash, emacs

I am using emacs key-bindings in bash. To move one character back, I have to press C-b twice. Is there a way to avoid this ?

I am having the same problem while running emacs editor also. If I start a C-s forward search and I enter some wrong characters that are not in the file, emacs shows search failed, and to correct the characters, I have to press Backspace key twice. Is there a solution for this too ?

Comment: this is strange behaviour. In my bash with emacs-bindings all is as expected. maybe you x-modemap is defunct? or you have a meta-binding C-b you are not aware of?

Comment: In addition to @PeterMiehle's comment above, which terminal do you use? When speaking of emacs, are you running it in a terminal or in X?

Comment: @PeterMiehle You were right. I was running bash within tmux and the prefix key for tmux was C-b, hence the problem... I had completely overlooked it. thank you. But the problem with emacs editor itself is still there... probably something silly there too.

Comment: @Francesco Now, I have no problems in bash emacs keybindings. The problem was tmux. But with emacs editor, I still have to press Backspace twice. I run emacs in X and not from any terminal.